# Block javascript file from executing

Tags: javascript, html, security

Consider these files:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="remove">This will be removed!</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
document.getElementById("remove").innerHTML = ("");
```

Is there a way to block `script.js` from executing?

This is for a CTF challange

Maybe I should also mention that I cant edit any of these.

Comment: when do you want it to be removed?

Comment: WHY do you want it to not execute? Are you trying to bypass a TOS on a free server?

Comment: Why do you want to block the execution? If not needed remove the inclusion of JS file from HTML file.

Comment: clarify, do you want to block it by another javascript or locally? If locally,you can disable js in browser.

Comment: I want to block it on a server that i dont have access to. This is for a CTF challange!

Comment: @BirhanNega Before dom is loaded

Comment: Can it run after the dom has loaded?

Comment: @wazz How do you mean? If it runs after, then the text will get removed

Comment: if you can't edit any files you cannot stop it from executing .you can stop it on your local machine if you want

Comment: @vonhact So? Anyway, it doesn't matter, I just got your updated post that says you can't edit anything so, nevermind.

Comment: @FastSnail How can I stop it on my local machine?

Comment: @vonhact yes there are several ways.for example using fiddler you can replace the content of your js file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false);
 
function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
  document.getElementById("remove").innerHTML = ("");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="remove">This will be removed!</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I dont have access to the file.

Comment: Then create an user script with e.g. [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/scripts.php)